# Select text between BBCode tags when inserting

Tags: jquery, select, text

So I have a `textarea` with the option to insert BBCode tags with the buttons above.

[image: Textarea]

When I click a button, it will insert the tags with the word *"text"*  between them.

[image: Textarea]

But what I'd like to achieve is when a tag is inserted, then the text between the tags is selected/highlighted, like this, so that when the user continues typing, they will be writing between the tags already, and they don't need to click/touch there first.

[image: Textarea]

This is how my current code works/looks like:

```js
$("#bbcode li").on("click",".bbcode",function(){
        let textarea = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("textarea");
        let tag = $(this).attr("data-tag");
        let text = tag == "hr" ? "" : "text";

        let selectStart = textarea[0].selectionStart;
        let selectEnd = textarea[0].selectionEnd;
        let selObj = document.getSelection(); 
        let selectedText = selObj.toString();
        let insert;

        let allText = textarea.val();
        let sel = allText.substring(selectStart, selectEnd);

        if (selectedText.length != 0) {
            let insert=allText.substring(0, selectStart)+"["+tag+"]  "+sel+"  [/"+tag+"]"+allText.substring(selectEnd, allText.length);
            textarea.val(insert);
        } 
        else{
            insert = "["+tag+"]   "+text+"   [/"+tag+"]";
            insertBBC(textarea,insert);
        }
        textarea.focus();
    });
    
    function insertBBC(textarea,insert){
        let cursorPos = textarea.prop('selectionStart');
        let v = textarea.val();
        let textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );
        let textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );
        textarea.val(textBefore+insert+textAfter);
    }
```

```css
textarea{
height:200px;width:500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="background: white;" id="bbcode" class="m-0 p-0 list-unstyled bg-light">

    <li class="mb-1 d-inline-block">
     <button data-tag="b" value="bold" title="bold" class="bg-light text-dark  bbcode m-0 p-1 border-0">
      <i class="fas fa-bold"></i>
     </button>
    </li>

    <li class="mb-1 d-inline-block">
     <button data-tag="i" value="italic" title="italic" class="bg-light text-dark  bbcode m-0 p-1 border-0">
      <i class="fas fa-italic"></i>
     </button>
    </li>

    <li class="mb-1 d-inline-block">
     <button data-tag="u" value="underline" title="underline" class="bg-light text-dark  bbcode m-0 p-1 border-0">
      <i class="fas fa-underline"></i>
     </button>
    </li>

    <li class="mb-1 d-inline-block">
     <button data-tag="s" value="strikethrough" title="strikethrough" class="bg-light text-dark  bbcode m-0 p-1 border-0">
      <i class="fas fa-strikethrough"></i>
     </button>
    </li>
       </ul>
<textarea></textarea>
```

The variable `text` contains the word *"text"*, so somehow I should force selection on it, but I have no idea how do it unfortunately.

I'd like to avoid stacking these selections, so the best would be if only the last inserted text would be selected.

PS: Please do not attempt to entirely change to code. Even if it's not the best, I need it mostly as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a great solution while searching. Found this [Jquery plugin](https://madapaja.github.io/jquery.selection/), and it is very good. Really simple, easy to understand, and works perfectly.